# How can I get the default disabled color?

Tags: android

I have the following color:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#9D9FA2" />
    <item android:color="#2f566d"/>
</selector>
```

However, the disabled color `#9D9FA2` for this custom color is not matching the default disabled colors.

How can I get and set the default disabled color?

Comment: Have you tried to remove that selector? Maybe if you do, system will use it's own disabled color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case it was:

```
@android:color/secondary_text_dark
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for the color in `android.R.color.` This class has all the colors used by your current `compileSdkVersion`.

Answer (score 0):

Add some Alpha Value before color code . Eg. If your color code is #9D9FA2 then u tried your disable by adding alpha color like #009D9FA2 ~ #AA9D9FA2(#<0-A><0-A>9D9FA2)